# jQuery: $(this) and other variables in the context

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following script:

```
<script src="~/js/store-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   var global = $(this);
    var wasclicked = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            global.wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            global.wasclicked = 0;
        });

        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            if (global.wasclicked == 1) {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
            $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
                var url = '/' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
                var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
                $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#DistrictID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                        items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#DistrictID').html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's objective is to:

- Identify if I'm opening or closing the modal window.
- If I'm opening the modal window, populate a dropdownlist [A] with certain information
- When another dropdownlist [B] changes it's value, update [A] value

**Question:**

- Is it correct the use of `$(this)` in this script? I ask it because, although it works, if I put a breakpoint on this line:

  var global = $(this);

I get an error on the debugger: Failed to load resource - 404 not found:

[image]

**Update:**

After applying the suggested changes the problem persists, which might be sign of another problem in the background. For this I update the result of the Html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Index - Plataforma Fantasy Park</title>


        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?v=qcV1wr-bn4NoBtxYqghmy1WIBvxeoe8vQlCowLG-cng"></script>
        <script src="/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js?v=X_58s5WblGMAw9SpDtqnV8dLRNCawsyGwNqnZD0Je_s"></script>
        <script src="/js/site.js?v=ViqmmChOp_51fH3dM_KEQAFClKU0vp0UrxlREwyHKHc"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-lumen.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/nestednavbar.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Plataforma Fantasy Park</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="/HechosLiquidadors/IndexAdmin">Liquidaciones</a></li>
                            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Máquinas <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1">Registro</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines">Datos Comerciales</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines/Workshop">Datos de Fabricación</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/Machines/Familias">Familias y Tipos</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1">Gestión</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines/Management">Máquinas</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines/Contadores">Contadores</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Tiendas <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Stores">Registro</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/Stores/Management">Liquidadores</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Proveedores <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/Suppliers/Supplier">Fabricantes y Marcas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Suppliers/Dealer">Dealers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                            <li><a href="/">Gastos</a></li>
                            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Usuarios <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/User">Usuarios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/ApplicationRole">Roles</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
        </ul>


<form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/Account/SignOff">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a title="Manage" href="/Manage">Hello adelgado!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8P12Ot7bDOBImhnZFhlI8qHPFz5Z8vuFfE8MbZPcoEDO8l20qrWS3FDx0GClCFhR3NVR5F2ysRwcKkbQ1FRaxGYDU-VJsNFpqMnyDmONltKFE6YINgnCRcBc0GSa0tnSvgJCDRrrfROVsWQRmvTIylwUR2nL5YDkJfNVwzdq9wdb8utLT5rXhZeANCwvGMFWvQ" /></form>

    </div>
</div>
</nav>




<h2>Tiendas</h2>

<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action-store" class="btn btn-primary" href="/Stores/Create">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Nueva Tienda
        </a>
</div>
<p></p>
<table id="stores" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tienda
            </th>
            <th>
                Dirección
            </th>
            <th>
                Área
            </th>
            <th>
                Distrito
            </th>
            <th>
                Cadena
            </th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>


<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-action-store-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-action-store" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - Plataforma Fantasy Park</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

<script src="/js/store-index.js?v=xMseET7-q434oUXfBjpd5QKjSw8t0R0P_mGdZorHwB0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var global = this;
    var wasclicked = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            global.wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            global.wasclicked = 0;
        });

        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            if (global.wasclicked == 1) {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
            $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
                var url = '/' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
                var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
                $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#DistrictID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                        items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#DistrictID').html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I also include the result of the network tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `global` variable and directly access `wasclicked`:

```
var wasclicked = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
        wasclicked = 1;
    };

    $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        wasclicked = 0;
    });

etc.....
```

Comment: Uhm, ok, I just did that, but I got the same error which is odd. https://i.imgur.com/OltGv0i.png It seems the problem is hidding somewhere else

Comment: That error makes no sense. Perhaps there is an issue with your html file. Please post the whole thing.

Comment: Updated at the end of the question.

Comment: I have no idea. That line is not referring to an HTTP call, so that status code is out of place. Perhaps try in another browser and see if you get an error?

Comment: haha :( I'll try with another browsers but yes, at the begining I thought it was because of a bad reference for jquery inside the view but that doesn't seem the case either